# C# DataGridView - deleting a row from the underlying BindingList (user highlights row , presses Del) , removes the next row from the view

Tags: datagridview, delete-row, bindinglist

C# DataGridView - deleting a row from the underlying BindingList (user highlights row and presses Del) and refreshing the grid removes the next row from the view.

I am using the UserDeletingRow event to remove the item from my underlying BindingList.
I then either grd.Refersh() or I re-query the database and rebind the grid to the BindingList, however the view takes out the next row in both cases. When I debug, the row is still in my BindingList. I need to press my Search Button again (which my own re-query procedure calls) to get all the data to show.

This was the result of many efforts and searching many articles which said I should rebind my grid to the datasource.

If I take the Refersh or re-query out of the user deleting event and put it in UserDeletedRow, I get the "Index x does not have a Value" error. I also get this error if I add an EndEdit call.

I don't want to have to add a Delete button but would prefer the user to delete the row by selecting the whole row and pressing delete.

Code:

```
    private void grdRequests_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.Index == -1) return;

        Request r = (Request)e.Row.DataBoundItem;

        if (r.RequestID != null && r.RequestID != 0)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            if (r.Approved)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You may not delete this Request, it has been approved", "Delete Request", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                DataController.DeleteRequest((int)r.RequestID);
                GridRequestsData.RemoveAt(e.Row.Index);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error deleteing request : " + ex.Message);
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        else
        {
            //not in the database, just remove the row
            if (!grdRequests.CurrentRow.IsNewRow)
            {
                GridRequestsData.RemoveAt(e.Row.Index);
            }
        }

        RefreshGridDataSource();
        //grdRequests.Refresh();
        
    }
```